# socket beginreceive Interrupts stream receiving

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, stream

I've coded a program which passes screenshos from computers over the net.
it's work on stream which i serialize to a networkstream every couple second to send the screen shot.
here is the code:

```
 NetworkStream stream;
 byte[] inBytes;
 BinaryFormatter bFormat;
 Bitmap inImage;
 int count = 0;

  public void startListening()
  {
       bFormat = new BinaryFormatter();
       stream = client.GetStream();

       while (true)
       {
            try
            {
                inBytes = bFormat.Deserialize(stream) as byte[];
                inImage = ByteToImage(inBytes);

                theImage.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)inImage;
                count++;
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

it's working pretty fine,but i've ecounterd a problem when i was trying to 
use the beginreceive on the tcp client  when it's connected

```
      StateObject state = new StateObject();
      state.workSocket = tcpClient.Client;
      tcpClient.Client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0
                   ,new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), state);
```

i left the onreceive method empty to make sure the problem isnt in the code in the method itself

```
  public void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
  {}
```

the receive method works fine(tried to use a messagebox) but it's affect the  serialization of the stream and im getting this error `system.runtime.serialization.serializationexception no map for object` 
any idea guys? i tried to use diffrent threads..etc didnt really worked

the stream comes from another program.. client which send it i didnt post it's code here because i dont think the problem comes from there... it's somthing in the server : (

here's the code in the beginreceive for who asked

```
 public void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        String content = String.Empty;

        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;
        int bytesRead;

        if (handler.Connected)
        {

            // Read data from the client socket. 
            try
            {
                bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {


                    // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                    state.sb.Remove(0, state.sb.Length);
                    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                                     state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));




                    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                       new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), state);

                }
                else
                {
                    String remoteIP = ((IPEndPoint)handler.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
                    String remotePort = ((IPEndPoint)handler.RemoteEndPoint).Port.ToString();
                    DisconnectClient(remoteIP, remotePort);
                }



            }

            catch (SocketException socketException)
            {

                //WSAECONNRESET, the other side closed impolitely
                if (socketException.ErrorCode == 10054 || ((socketException.ErrorCode != 10004) && (socketException.ErrorCode != 10053)))
                {

                    // Complete the disconnect request.
                    String remoteIP = ((IPEndPoint)handler.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
                    String remotePort = ((IPEndPoint)handler.RemoteEndPoint).Port.ToString();
                    DisconnectClient(remoteIP, remotePort);

                    handler.Close();
                    handler = null;
                    MessageBox.Show("disconnected");

                }
            }


            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message + "\n" + exception.StackTrace);

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: How can you leave the `OnReceive` empty? Shouldn't it at least have `EndReceive`? Why are you using `BeginReceive` *in combination* with using a `NetworkStream`? That sounds fishy - it feels like they're going to be stealing each others' data. TCP isn't quite that simple :) Also, are you really using binary formatter to deserialize a *byte array*? Are you sure that makes sense?

Comment: @Luaan bro i left OnReceive empty on purpose because i just wanted to make sure the problem isnt in the code itself(the code in the OnReceive) what's the problem with deserialzing a byte array?  i'll show u the client code bro                                                                                                                        this is what i use in the client `Image w = Image.FromStream(ms);
                        bFormat.Serialize(s, Compress(ImageToByte(w)));`          w is the new image and than i serialize it into a networkstream as array of byte

Comment: Oh, is it just that you don't know what `BeginReceive` does? You don't need to call it to make the `NetworkStream` receive data, that's completely separate. In fact, I'm pretty sure that's what's causing your issues. If you expect your code to work in any way with no code in `OnReceive`, it certainly suggets so. Just comment out the `BeginReceive` call entirely.

Comment: @Luaan ty very much for the help bro but if i would like to get some data from the client? how can i receive it? through the network stream?

Comment: Yeah, that's the whole point of using the `NetworkStream` - it gives you a simple bi-directional stream between the client and the server. The `NetworkStream` internally uses `Receive`/`BeginReceive` or similar to handle the actual reading - when you *also* start an asynchronous receive operation, you're messing with that - you'll get the first segment of data that arrives, and the `NetworkStream` will only get the rest - missing the header that tells the `BinaryFormatter` to interpret the data as `byte[]`, leading to the exception you see (and missing part of the data, of course).

Comment: TCP is stream-based, not message-based, so you only ever have that one stream of data. You don't have mutiple simultaneous streams over a single TCP connection - there's only the one. That also means that it's rather tricky handling multiple threads posting data on the stream - it can get mangled in very many interesting ways, and it's quite tricky dispatching the message handlers. It's not a simple "write on one side, read on the other".

Comment: @Luaan luaan there isnt a really way to know when the client got disconnected in networkstream... i dont want to send somthing from the server to client every second and than if there is an error to know that it disconnected... i need use also begin receive... look at my post i edited it

Comment: Yes there is - the `Read` (`EndReceive` in the non-stream case) is going to return zero. TCP will not tell you the connection died, ever, unless you actively send data - as simple as that. You can do the same thing you're doing in `BeginReceive` using `NetworkStream` - they're equivallent, the main difference being that `NetworkStream` is ... well, a stream. But TCP is *also* a stream, unlike, say, UDP.

Comment: Try to imagine what the `TcpClient` has to do. You're using two different ways of receiving data at the same time, fine. But how should `TcpClient` know which you want to go to the `OnReceive` handler, and which should be sent to the `NetworkStream`? As far as TCP is concerned, there is only one stream. So the first one to call the `BeginReceive` is going to get the first batch of data, the second one will get the second part etc. The fact that you have to touch the underlying socket to do this should have tipped you off - there's no reason to use anything but `TcpClient` here.

Comment: @Luaan ty for the help but why should sending image through the networkstream trigger the on receive call?  I didn't use any socket send method at the client side. .. ..just serialized it into a networkstream. ..it shouldn't even bother. ..no?

Comment: It's not quite clear what's happening where - could you edit your question to make it clear what happens on the server and what on the client? Ideally, *all* the sends and receives of both the client and the server.

Comment: @Luaan Allright bro im not home yet so I'll add later thanks for help

Comment: @Luaan  have a look here bro http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383334/using-networkstream-with-sockets i've asked and explained better my question :)

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't really help much. But the point is still the same - if you want to use the single stream to work with multiple possible "logical" data streams, you'll need a lot more groundwork - and you still have to keep the reading in one place, because TCP is *not* message based. So prefix every logical message you send with some type ID (e.g. `0x01` for a screenshot message, `0x02` for stats), and in your receive loop, read the first byte to decide what to do with the rest of the "message". But do keep just the one read - it's almost impossible to manage multiple with TCP.